# Uploading CSV to S3 after for loop

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a requirement where I need to create a CSV file with values read from a list and then upload it to S3. I do it as follows

```
 with open('/tmp/mycsv.csv', mode='w',  newline='') as csv_file:
     fieldnames = ['DomainName', 'Subject']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
     writer.writeheader()
           
     for x in certificates:
         writer.writerow({'DomainName': 'hardcodeString1','Subject':'hardcodeString2'})
     s3 = boto3.client('s3')
     response = s3.upload_file('/tmp/mycsv.csv', 'my-bucket', 'mycsv.csv')
```

But the CSV file is not uploaded, If I remove the for loop, this works fine with hard coded values there is ano issues uploading the file. I even added a pause after writing row to see if it gets uploaded , there are no errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you uploading the file from within the with context? The changes are guaranteed to be persisted only after the context ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you should be doing to ensure that the changes to the file are persisted:

```py
with open('/tmp/mycsv.csv', mode='w',  newline='') as csv_file:
            fieldnames = ['DomainName', 'Subject']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
           
            for x in certificates:
                writer.writerow({'DomainName': x[DomainName],'Subject':x[Subject]})
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.upload_file('/tmp/mycsv.csv', 'my-bucket', 'mycsv.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks that helped create the file in S3 but its not writing rows to it, I tried replacing variables with hard coded strings but only see the header no rows

Comment: `certificates` is empty

Comment: no I changed the values to be plain strings no variables, but dont see it written

Comment: I don't follow. Could you please update your post or mine with the details?

Comment: Got it. Since the hardcoded strings are within the for loop, if `cerfificates` is empty, the for loop won't get executed. Remove the for loop and fix the indentation to check your implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216518/discussion-between-balaji-ambresh-and-user-mda).

Comment: HI would this work within a nested loop? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62542225/nested-loops-in-python-and-csv-file @Balaji Ambresh

Comment: @user_mda What are you trying to accomplish?