# Nested loops in Python and CSV file

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, nested-loops

I have a python lambda with nested for loop

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    acc_ids = json.loads(os.environ.get('ACC_ID'))
    with open('/tmp/newcsv.csv', mode='w',  newline='') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = ['DomainName', 'Subject', 'Status', 'RenewalEligibility', 'InUseBy']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for acc_id in acc_ids:
            try:
                //do something
                for region in regions_to_scan:
                    try:
                       // do something
                        if something:
                            for x in list:
                                // get values for row
                                writer.writerow('write rows here')
                        
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                        continue 
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                continue
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3.upload_file('/tmp/newcsv.csv', 'my-bucket', 'newcsv.csv')
```

This is not uploading the file in S3, from other conversations I made sure that the uploading of the file is after the writing context is done. Can someone evaluate my script?

Comment: **Did you look in CloudWatch Logs to find any error messages?** I would suggest that you start on getting the upload to work, then worry about the file contents. Therefore, just try a `download_file()` to get some local content, then try to `upload_file()` that file to confirm that the upload is working. If it _is_ working, then the problem is probably with the code that creates the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the loop and the lambda were correct. The timeout on the lambda function was set to 10 secs and it never reached the code to upload the file. Increasing the timeout on lambda fixed my problem